# Add an item with lookup field using object model SP2010?

Tags: object-model

Can someone please post sample code which shows how to deal with a lookup column during an item insert (using object model).

Here is the basic framework for an insert:

```
SPListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem();

    // Text field - very easy
    oListItem["Title"] = SomeStringValue;

    //Hyperlink - requires some work but format is like this:
    oListItem["HyperlinkField"] = URL+ ", " + Desc;
```

So what I'm missing is how to add a lookup field, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're looking for is the [SPFieldLookupValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvalue.aspx) class. MSDN has a good example.

In short, something like:

```
SPListItem lookedUpItem =  GetItemSomeHow();
newItem[lookupField] = new SPFieldLookupValue( lookedUpItem.ID, lookedUpItem.Title);
newItem.Update();
```

I'd also recommend setting your hyperlink field using the [SPFieldUrlValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx) class.

Comment: Very nicely done, didn't know about the SPFieldURLValue...